# Having issues returning value of instance variables from class

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm sure this is a simple question but it's driving me nuts.  I have a method in a model class, actual_effort, which is calling a function in a helper class.  The function in the helper class is setting an instance variable which I should be able to see back in the model class but can't.  I debug it using the console and still can't see it.  I can display the variable in the helper class, with the commented out puts, and this proves it's being set.

Model class

```
class WorkFlow < ActiveRecord::Base
  require 'helpertest'

  def actual_effort    
    v1 = HelperTest.new()
    v1.setActualEffort(1000)
    v1.actual_effort
  end 
end
```

Helper class

```
class HelperTest
  attr_accessor :actual_effort

  def setActualEffort(eff)
    actual_effort = eff

    #puts actual_effort
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use self to reference a member variables.

```
class HelperTest
  attr_accessor :actual_effort

  def setActualEffort(eff)
    self.actual_effort = eff

    #puts actual_effort
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

actual_effort in your setActualEffort method is a local variable. You want a instance variable instead. That is

```
def setActualEffort(eff)
  @actual_effort = eff

  #puts actual_effort
end
```

Note: This is equivalent to self.actual_effort = eff